# How do I re-launch the Coded UI Test Recorder for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with Feature Pack 2 to experiment with recording Silverlight UI tests using the Coded UI Test feature.

I've created a new test, launched the recorder and recorded some basic interaction, but I'm unable to figure out how to to re-launch the recorder to add a new test. I'm hoping that I don't have to add a new test .cs file for each test I record... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either create a new Test from the solution explorer window as normal or create one in code by adding a test method and then right click inside the method and the generate option should be there